# Why does Google review an older app bundle rather than the new one?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to upload my app to google play store and have been getting rejected based on an old version of my app not being compliant with family policies. Why does google not review the most recent version of my app? All the appropriate changes have been made to it and it is compliant to their policies now, but they still reject my app based on an older version. How can I resolve this issue? (they review the 5th app bundle while the recent one that i uploaded was 12)

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the old outdated apk from the artifacts page. Follow these steps to delete the older apk and try the verification again:

1. Open Google Play Console
2. Go to your project
3. Go to the "Release" section of the side-bar
4. Go to the "App bundle explorer"
5. Find the APK and click "Delete APK".

Comment: Hi, how do you delete an active app bundle?

Comment: @ParamaDharmika Both an aab and apk should be viewed in the same menu. Deleting them should be the exact same. Where have you looked?